# Append a character to specific multiple columns in specific rows

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I have a file I want to add specific character to multiple specific columns in specific rows. For eaxample my file is

```
shirts pants tshirts greet 
100000 11111 1200000 131313
123456 15823 1542358 752256
```

I want to add a character sold to all columns after second (there can be multiple columns, unknown) to only the first row. I can select first row using and columns using

```
NR<2 and NF>2
```

But how do I append to each fields? I want my answer to be

```
shirts pants soldtshirts soldgreet 
100000 11111 1200000 131313
123456 15823 1542358 752256
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right about the use of `NR<2` and `NF>2`. Something like this can be a solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) $i="sold"$i}1' a
shirts pants soldtshirts soldgreet
100000 11111 1200000 131313
123456 15823 1542358 752256
```

On `NR==1` (first line) it loops from 3rd to last field appending "sold" to each one. Then the `1` evaluates as true and prints the whole line in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1s/\S\+/sold&/3g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$1"\t"$2;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)x=x"\tsold"$i;$0=x}1' file
```